# Более короткий способ инкремента min или max значения

Tags: python, python-3.x

Очень часто бывает так, что нужно добавить 1 к *минимальному* значению, или отнять 1 от *максимального*. Яркий пример этому - два указателя, которые двигаются друг к другу.

Возьмём как пример ситуацию:

```
# Инициализируем два указателя и будем их постепенно двигать друг к другу
heights = [1, 8, 6, 2, 5, 4, 8, 3, 7]
left = 0
right = len(height) - 1

while left < right:
    if heights[left] > heights[right]:
        right -= 1
    else:
        left += 1
```

В цикле `while` логика **+= 1** и **-= 1** реализована на **4** строчках, почему мы не можем сделать например так?

```
min(left, right) += 1
max(left, right) -= 1
```

Ведь если мы посмотрим на адрес в памяти у этих переменных, то увидим что у `left` (минимального значения) и функции `min` от левого и правого указателя одинаковые адреса

```
print(hex(id(left))) -> 0x956e00 (одинак)
print(hex(id(right))) -> 0x956e20
print(hex(id(min(left, right)))) -> 0x956e00 (одинак)
```

Что должно в теории разрешать подобные операции во втором блоке с кодом.

Есть ли более короткие альтернативы, которые делают тоже самое, но занимают меньше строк или может быстрее работают?

Comment: `реализована на 4 строчках` - но она легко читается и понимается

Comment: Не могу это отрицать, но в данном случае используется всего 2 значения, что требует только 1 операции сравнения для выявления минимума. Условие будет уже не в 4 строчки, если значений будет всего 3 или 4.

Comment: Но в данном примере вы знаете, какое из значений меньше, и сравниваете косвенные величины.

Comment: Не могу понять, а что вы подразумеваете под min(left, right) += 1 например?   Результат-то нигде не сохраняется в такой форме. Приведите полный пример вашего варианта. Тогда можно будет и и понять и сравнить производительность.

Comment: @passant, В третьем блоке я просто как пример указал, аналог чего хотелось бы видеть в Python. Если запустить тот код, то выведет ошибку конечно. Просто в других языках, которые поддерживают ссылки и указатели (например в C++), можно в функции найти минимальное значение и вернуть указатель на обьект, и далее с ним уже делать какие либо действия. Как пример можно рассмотреть список целых чисел, возьмём `[1, 9, 2, 5, 6, 1, 2, 4]`. Нужно найти индекс с наибольшим значением и увеличить значение на 1. Можно ли сделать коротко, желательно без цикла `for` или условий?

Comment: Только в примере комментария цифры не изменяются путём `+= 1`, можно для удобства взять что-то вроде этого: https://pastebin.com/JadjYsBr

Comment: `+=` для чисел меняет `id`. В Питоне нет lvalue. По этим двум причинам нельзя придать смысл выражению `min(left, right) += 1`.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение, очень жаль. Интересно, много бы проблем можно было решить, если бы min() возвращал не копию значения (как выяснилось), а указатель на него...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так и не смог понять, что-же на самом деле интересует ТС. Но основываясь на комментарии, который содержит вот этот вопрос:

> Как пример можно рассмотреть список целых чисел, возьмём [1, 9, 2, 5,
> 6, 1, 2, 4]. Нужно найти индекс с наибольшим значением и увеличить
> значение на 1. Можно ли сделать коротко, желательно без цикла for или
> условий?

отвечаю на него. Можно.

Если у вас действительно список, то например, вот так:

```
lt=[1, 9, 2, 5, 6, 1, 2, 4]
ind_lt_max=lt.index(max(lt))
print(ind_lt_max+1, lt[ind_lt_max+1])
```

Если у вас еще и массив numpy -  то еще проще:

```
nl=np.array(lt)
ind_nl_max = np.argmax(nl)
print(ind_nl_max+1,nl[ind_nl_max+1])
```

В обоих случаях выводится "2 2" - индекс элемента, следующего за максимальным в списке (массиве) и само значение, найденное по этому индексу. Как и просили. Коротко, без циклов и условий.

Одно добавление. Как человек, которые проработал почти два десятка лет на С++ прежде чем перейти на Python - мне понятен шок разработчика :-), привыкшего работать с указателями, и не найдя их в Python. Потом приходит понимание, что это никак не сказывается на выразительных возможностях языка -  просто *думать* программисту надо не на языке С++, а на языке Python. Только и всего.

Comment: Ладно, так понимаю что придётся пользоваться тем, что и умел раньше собственно. С массивом NumPy инкремент мне больше понравился, чем с обычным списком. С обычным листом чтобы получить максимальное значение - нужно пройтись по списку O(n) + потом индексация O(n), что не супер круто для языка, который не быстр по природе.